# How to create SharePoint page layout based on existing .aspx file

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have an existing page layout that I want to slightly modify and use. When I upload the modified file to a pages library it works fine but I would like to be able to select that page as a layout going forward, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to upload your aspx into the master page gallery (site setting => Master pages and page layouts).

Change the type to "Page Layout" and assign a content type (e.g. Welcome Page) to make the template appear in your Library when you crate a new page.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to sharepoint, in fact no experience. I uploaded a aspx page.how do I generate a design file(html) for that aspx page layout. btw, I created the page layout directly from the sharepoint designer, so I can add controls and save.